# Create field on open ArcGIS map - not saved

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, field-calculator, fields-attributes, dynamic-layer

I am using ArcGIS desktop with an SDE feature layer with enterprise data that I do not have rights to edit.  The data changes weekly but I need a field that is sum of 2 current fields without creating a separate table that would not reflect the weekly changes.

Answer (score 1):

Query Layers are designed for this kind of layers.

In Arcmap: File > Add Data > Add Query Layer...

see also this [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_query_layer/00s500000027000000) for details.

Your query should look like:

```sql
SELECT field1,field2, field1+field2 as field3 FROM Test.dbo.TableName
```